# Should you use a comma/period after "Thanks"/"Regards" in email signatures?

Tags: punctuation, commas, email, periods

Normal practice is to end emails with a *Thanks* or *Regards*. My question is should there be a comma or a period or nothing after *Thanks/Regards*?

> Thanks,
>       John Doe

Or

> Thanks.
>       John Doe

Or

> Thanks
>       John Doe

I have seen all three versions as part of email signatures. Which among these three is correct? Why?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you consider it to be a phrase that simply spans two lines, I'd say:

> Thanks,
>   John Doe

is correct. Without the comma it would imply that you're thanking John Doe. It's certainly the one I use personally, not that that's a particularly good back-up for this answer. I can't say I've ever seen anyone use it with a ".", that just looks wrong to me.

Comment: I would add that the version without the comma would most likely be viewed as casualness/sloppiness, while the version with the period would probably be viewed as a stylistic thing — it's something I would have done when I was 14.

Answer (score 10):

The

> Thanks.

form tends to seem vaguely abrupt, clipped, perfunctory, and rude to me.

Comment: Excuse me, but what's rude about it?

Comment: @Dia: because of the short, clipped nature of that sentence, it might be read with a sarcastic tone.

Comment: Agree, but not extremely. I see it as 10% rude, but I always give the sender the benefit of that doubt :P Still, comma is better.