# Punctuation after valediction

Tags: punctuation, commas, letter-writing, periods, valediction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should you use a comma/period after “Thanks”/“Regards” in email signatures?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2329/should-you-use-a-comma-period-after-thanks-regards-in-email-signatures)

When writing a letter, do we put a comma or a period after the valediction?

1. > Sincerely,
   >   John Doe
2. > Sincerely.
   >   John Doe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_letter#Punctuation) is the only acceptable punctuation to place after the valediction:

> Sincerely,
>   John Doe

This is because the period is only necessary at the end of a sentence or abbreviation.  The comma, on the other hand, usually separates related phrases within a sentence.  In this case, the context is not a sentence (*Sincerely, John Doe*), but convention has established the usage of a comma in a letter's closing in much the same capacity as in a sentence.